# Logo email not changing

Tags: configuration, email, email-templates, rwd, design

I'm using Magento's default sales emails.

I've inserted my logo as `logo_email.gif` in all themes

found > `skin/frontend/theme/images`,

uploaded in backend `Configuration > Design > Transactional Emails`,

cleared cache in backend and > `var/cache`. Yet, it still shows Magento's logo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like browser cache not reloading since it has the same name.  Try to rename your image in your transactional template and of course the uploaded file and try again.

When an image has the same name, browsers will sometimes not refresh even after a cache flush.

Comment: If the above solution works, please mark accepted. Also you may be interested in cachebuster free extension which automatically changes file names of you use compressed CSS and js

Comment: I'm not using a transactional template. I'm using Magento's default templates. I will just clear browser cache. Since it's a recent website, it won't be a problem. Thank you!

Comment: That may or may not work immediately.  Depends on expire headings in some situations at the server config level. It's very easy to use those templates and modify. Let me know if you need help if browser cache doesn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well.
My images were uploaded to `/media/email/logo`, but the permissions were `640`. Changing the permission of the image I wanted to use to `666` was all I found necessary. If the image next to the upload under Transactional emails is the broken image symbol, this is very likely your issue.

Comment: With me it was folder permission and file permission issue.